# Get qty of products in an order

Tags: php, magento, orders

i would like to know how to get the unique quantity of products in a order

i have tried these (in /renderer/default.phtml):

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
```

$qnt = round($_order->getData('total_qty_ordered'), 0);
but this returns the total number of products, and i need only total of different products.

thanks!

Comment: after place order you want this information

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an order may contain many products. Hence qty of a product is not assigned at order level but is is assigned at item level. You can get that as below:

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $items){
$qty = $items->getQty();
}
```

Comment: hi, now resulting in: 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of different products by loading the visible items of an order (since Magento stores two order items for configurable products, one for the parent and one for the child, this method provides only one item in such cases) and count the number of array entries.

For example in this way:

```
$_order = $this->getOrder();
$qnt = count($_order->getAllVisibleItems());
```